# Stuck at Grub and can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub-legacy

I was just installing an update and rebooted when i got stuck in the Grub boot screen.
I can choose between S10 Jumpstart, s10 Netboot, s10 Jumpstart console B (Dell) and Netboot Console B (Dell). If i go into the grub terminal and type 'ls', i get the following: 'Error 27: Unrecognized command'

GNU GRUB version 0.95

Comment: Pretend you were someone other than yourself reading this. Would they have enough information to diagnose your problem? Would they know the version of Ubuntu you were running, what the update you were installing was, or what kind of pc specs you have? Why is your grub so old?